# Using edittext to change mac address android bluetooth app

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, bluetooth, android-edittext

I have a question about using edittext function in android.

I have the following code in the main activity of my app:

```
  private static String address = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
  //Then I have the on create below this
```

In that line, the MAC address has to be manually edited and recompiled every time. How could I use an edittext in another activity and get the value the user inputs and have that replace the mac address.

To clarify the second activity, it has an edittext area for user input, then it has a button for the user to confirm the information. What I want the activity to do is when the user clicks the button, it sends the MAC address to the main activity [above].

Also, I have various buttons in the main activity set up to send various Bluetooth signals. For example, the button fwd.id sends the signal 'Front' via Bluetooth:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    sendData("Front");
```

I was wondering that if on the same page [the second activity for configuration], I could create another edittext to alter the signal [in this case 'front'] being sent. For example, if the user wants to send the signal, 8 instead of 'front' they would input it into the edit text, click the same button as above for the mac address confirmation and the signal would change to whatever they input.

If someone could please help me out, that'd be great. Thank you in advance. If you need any more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand your question you can use intent.putExtra() method to pass the address from the edit text. This should look like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("macaddress", editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Now in another activity you can set the value of mac address to be the value carried by this intent

```
String address=getIntent().getExtras().getString("macaddress");
```

Hope its helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There can be various ways of accomplishing this:

1. Your address variable is already declared static, all you need to do is declare it public. Get the text from the EditText field and set the String address to required value.
   For example if your main activity is known as MainActivity then in the Second Activity you will do something like this:

   ```
   MainActivity.address = newAddress // newAddress will be a string coming in from value entered in the EditText field.
   ```
2. Starting the second Activity, which contains the EditText field, for result. That means when the second Activity is finished the onActivityResult method of the MainActivity will be called because this will be the Activity which would have initiated the Second Activity.

Then you can pass result from the EditText to your main Activity and update your String address in the method onActivityResult method.